# Java Spring Active profile in kubernetes Cluster

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, kubernetes

i want to start Java spring app with active profile...
I build Docker image in Gitlab CI/CD using maven wrapper ,

```
./mvnw compile jib:build -Dimage=image/sms-service:1
```

after that i deploy app in k8s....

now i want to run with active profile , what is best way? how can i define in k8s to run specific user

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sms-service
  namespace: sms-service
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sms-service
  replicas: 4 # tells deployment to run 2 pods matching the template
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sms-service
    spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: sms-service
        image: image/sms-service:1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: sms-service
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` environment variable to the profile(s) you want to run.

You can set it in the deployment yaml or at build time in your image but usually better to add it to deployment.

Comment: can you explain how to add in deployement ?  and where set SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE in java propertie ?

Comment: under `containers`, you can add `env`. Then key: value i.e. `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: prod`

Answer (score 1):

Create a new file, named `configmap.yaml` under the k8s config folder and add the following lines:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: blabla
  namespace: bla
data:
  application.yaml: |
    spring:
      profiles:
        active: prod (here goes the profile)
```

This tells Kubernetes to set this configuration when starting the container

Comment: Thats all ? is active : test is it correct?

Comment: That's all, `active: test` should do the trick.

Comment: Is it correct yea? https://ibb.co/t4yy5Mz 
application.yaml include deploy and service 
conf.yaml include your codes Configmap

Comment: I think we miss something

Comment: In linux machine i start with 
java -jar  -Dspring.profiles.active=test test.jar

Comment: Rename the file to `configmap.yaml`. Correct, that's the way you run from command line but in this case Kubernetes is taking care of that

Comment: what's name is application.yaml ?

Comment: Can you check kubernetes logs to see if it's taking that file in account?